# I want a spell checker plug in to html editable div?

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I have an editable div and applying it **CKeditor**. I want spell checker within. I have tried one plug in from :http://www.webspellchecker.net/samples/scayt-ckeditor-plugin.html

It gives following error

> Error parsing encrypted customer ID (Invalid data encoded string)

Any one have any solution on this. Please give me some solution on spell checker for inline editor.

Comment: Can you add enough code to reproduce the error in your question?

Comment: I have just copied n pasted code on the given link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SCAYT is a commercial service which has an ads-based free version. You either need to set `CKEDITOR.config.scayt_customerid` to `null` (gives you ads) or you need to buy the service.

Comment: thank you sir. can you provide some link for SCAYT where i can buy it?

Comment: `CKEDITOR.config.scayt_customerid = 'null';` is still giving me same error!!

Comment: To buy a license, go to http://ckeditor.com/addon/scayt. And `'null'` is still a string. Try `CKEDITOR.config.scayt_customerid = null;`

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way is to enable native spell checker from the browser.

```
config.disableNativeSpellChecker = false;
```

http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_spellcheck

Comment: but I think it is browser dependant and doesn't work on all browsers!!